# Is the symmetrical topology on $\mathbb{R}^1$ induced by some metric?

Tags: general-topology

I obtained some topology on $\mathbb{R}$. (Base of this topology is $(-a-e;-a+e)\cup(+a-e;+a+e)$.
The question is "can it be induced by some metric".
I suspect that no, becase identity of indiscernibles may not hold. (Since for every $a \neq 0$, $a$ and $-a$ are always in the same, arbitrary small open sets. )

But how to prove that there is no metric which creates such topology?

Comment: The property you refer to as "identity of indiscernibles" is called the "Hausdorff property" in topology. Metric spaces are always Hausdorff, so your space is not metrizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got really close. On any metric space $(M,d)$, if $x,y\in M$ and $x\ne y$, the sets $B_{d(x,y)/2}(x)$ and $B_{d(x,y)/2}(y)$ are open sets with empty intersection such that $x\in B_{d(x,y)/2}(x)$ and $y\in B_{d(x,y)/2}(y)$. However, in that topological space of yours, if $a>0$, you cannot find open sets $A$ and $A'$ such that $a\in A$, $-a\in A'$ and $A\cap A'=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

You just essentially did.

Since all basic open sets are invariant under the negation map $x\mapsto -x$, the same holds for union and intersections of basic open sets, hence *all* open sets are symmetric,as well as all closed sets. In particular, singleton sets  $\{a\}$ with $a\ne 0$ are *not* closed, but would be closed in a metric space.